# How to Update Stock Quantity Manually in Magento

Tags: php, web-services, magento, stock

I'm trying to update the stock quantity in magento manually.
I know it's possible but I don't know how to proceed...

I want to update the stock from a web service, and I'm searching how to list all my articles. Then, get the id of the article, send it to the web service, get the stock provides by the web service and to finish, update the stock in the database of Magento.

I'm a new user of Magento and your help will be really appreciate :)

Thank you so much guys!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

3 tables are mainly used to manage the stock :
`cataloginventory_stock`, `cataloginventory_stock_item` and `cataloginventory_stock_status`

If you need to update a product's stock quantity you will need to find the relevant line in the `cataloginventory_stock_item` table and edit the qty field:

Example (set qty to 100 for product ID 33) :

```
UPDATE cataloginventory_stock_item set qty=100 where product_id=33
```

Comment: Super! I will test it tomorrow morning ;) really thanks to you :)

Comment: No prob! I forgot to mention you will probably need to reindex stock data after doing that.

Comment: It works! Also, I found this tuto if someone needs to do the same thing than me ;): http://www.magentoblog.net/how-to-update-products-stock-directly-in-magento-database.html

Answer (score 1):

Exist following  solution

```
$stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item');
Mage::getResourceModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProductId($stockItem, $allProductsIDs[$sku]);

$dataStock['sku'] = $sku;
$dataStock['qty'] = $qty;
$dataStock['is_in_stock'] = $isInStock;
$dataStock['manage_stock'] = $stockData['manage_stock'];
$dataStock['use_config_manage_stock'] = $stockData['use_config_manage_stock'];

foreach($dataStock as $key1=>$value1) {
$stockItem->setData($key1, $value1);
}

$stockItem->save();
```